# How to get the corresponding comma-separated text for a string of comma separated codes?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I've a table, there is a column called "locations" which is in type of varchar(max). It carries string of comma-separated code, e.g. `'1, 3, 4'`. On the other hand, I've a table which map these code to some locations, e.g.

```
1 -- British
2 -- New Zealand
3 -- Hong Kong
4 -- Taiwan
```

My problem is, I'm making a VIEW which will map and replace the content of the column "locations" to the corresponding comma-separated text, e.g. `'1, 3, 4'` will be `'British, Hong Kong, Taiwan'`

This is really urgent for the company project, please kindly advise.

Thank you!

Regards,
William

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be simpler solutions to do this but here is one way.

Table structure

```
create table Locations(LocationID int, Location varchar(50))
create table OtherTable(ID int, Locations varchar(max))
```

Test data

```
insert into Locations values(1, 'Location <1>')
insert into Locations values(2, 'Location <2>')
insert into Locations values(3, 'Location <3>')
insert into Locations values(4, 'Location <4>')
insert into Locations values(5, 'Location <5>')

insert into OtherTable values (1, '')
insert into OtherTable values (2, '2')
insert into OtherTable values (3, '1, 3 ,5')
```

Query

```
;with cte as
(
  select 
    T.ID,
    coalesce(L.Location, '') as Location
  from OtherTable as T
    cross apply
      (select cast('<r>'+replace(T.Locations, ',', '</r><r>')+'</r>' as xml)) LocXML(XMLCol)
    cross apply
      LocXML.XMLCol.nodes('r') LocID(IDCol) 
    left outer join Locations as L
      on L.LocationID = LocID.IDCol.value('.', 'int')
)
select
  C1.ID,
  stuff((select ', '+C2.Location
         from cte as C2 
         where C1.ID = C2.ID
         for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') as Locations
from cte as C1
group by C1.ID
```

Result

```
ID  Locations
--- ----------------------------------------
1   
2   Location <2>
3   Location <1>, Location <3>, Location <5>
```